# Apache beam - Is it possible to write to an Excel file?

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I would like to create an Apache Beam pipeline for Dataflow to get data from a database, transform it and upload the result as Excel files (xls and xlsx) with style on GCP that I could then share.

The Apache POI library allows me to create Excel files with style but I fail to integrate it with Apache Beam in the pipeline creation process because it's not really a processing on the PCollection.

If anyone would have an idea how I could do this without having to write CSV.

Thanks